# Spark Cassandra Aggregation java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I've been trying to learn how to use Apache Spark, and I'm having issues trying to sum all the values in a column from Cassandra (using the datastax spark-cassandra-connector). Everything I try just results in **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**.

Here's the code I'm submitting to the spark master:

```
object Benchmark {
  def main( args: Array[ String ] ) {
    val conf    = new SparkConf()
                  .setAppName( "app" )
                  .set( "spark.cassandra.connection.host", "ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com" )
                  .set( "spark.cassandra.auth.username", "myusername" )
                  .set( "spark.cassandra.auth.password", "mypassword" )
                  .set( "spark.executor.memory", "4g" )
    val sc      = new SparkContext( conf )
    val tbl     = sc.cassandraTable( "mykeyspace", "mytable" )
    val res     = tbl.map(_.getFloat("sclrdata")).sum()

    println( "sum = " + res )
  }
}
```

Right now I only have a single spark worker node in my cluster, and it is definitely possible that given the size of the table, not all of it can fit in memory at once. However I didn't think this would be an issue since spark is supposed to lazily evaluate the commands, and summing all the values in a column shouldn't need to have the entire table reside in memory at once.

I'm very much a newbie to this topic, so any clarification as to why this wouldn't work or help as to how to do it correctly would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're completely right that is should not load everything into memory. Can you enable debug logging to see what is the split size? which version of the conector are you using? how many splits (spark partitions / tasks) get created - you can see that in the spark web console? where do you get the OOM - is it on the executor or the driver app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps spark is building the entire table as a single in memory partition so that it can do the mapping operations on it.

I thought spark was supposed to spill to disk rather than throw OutOfMemoryExceptions, but maybe it isn't able to spill if there is just a single partition.  I saw a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141998/why-apache-spark-is-performing-the-filters-on-client), and he solved it by specifying a split size like this:

```
conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Test");
        conf.setMaster("local[4]");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.1.15").
        set("spark.executor.memory", "2g").
        set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb", "67108864");
```

So try setting spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb in your conf.

I imagine this would allow spark to sum up chunks of the table and then evict those chunks from memory when it needs space for new chunks.

Another thing you could look into is specifying a storage level for the table RDD that would allow it to spill to disk.  I think you could do this by adding ".persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)".  The default appears to be MEMORY_ONLY.  See more information on storage levels [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html), in the RDD persistence section.

Comment: mapping in spark does not put the whole partition into memory

Comment: specifying the split size ended up fixing my issue. thanks for the help