# Apache Spark taking 5 to 6 minutes for simple count of 1 billon rows from Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using the Spark Cassandra connector.
It take 5-6 minutes for fetch data from Cassandra table. In Spark I have seen many tasks and Executor in log. The reason might be that Spark divided the process in many tasks!

Below is my code example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("local[4]")
            .setAppName("App_Name")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<Demo_Bean> empRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("dev",
            "demo");
    System.out.println("Row Count"+empRDD.count());
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question? :)

Comment: Obviously , i want to decrease time .

Comment: @karmadipdodiya Hi, how did you configure to take 5~6minutes for simple count of 1 billion rows? It took 10+ hours to do a simple count for me. What configuration of spark and cassandra did you do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching on Google i fond the issue in the latest spark-cassandra-connector.
The parameter `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb`  Default value is 64 MB which is being interpreted as 64 bytes in the code.
So try with
`spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb = 64 * 1024 * 1024 = 67108864`

Hear is an example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("local[4]")
            .setAppName("App_Name")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
            .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb","67108864");


    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<Demo_Bean> empRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("dev",
            "demo");
    System.out.println("Row Count"+empRDD.count());
}
```

Comment: For reference, here's the bug number which fixed the split size setting (MB vs B) in connector v1.3.0: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-208

Answer (score 7):

To speed it up you might try setting the spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb when you create the SparkConf.

It could be that the executors are trying to read all the rows into memory at once.  If they don't all fit, it might cause it to page the RDD to disk, resulting in the slow time.  By specifying a split size, it would count the rows in chunks and then discard them rather than paging to disk.

You can see an example of how to set the split size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154161/4339776).