# Spark SQL + Cassandra: bad performance

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm just starting using Spark SQL + Cassandra, and probably am missing something important, but one simple query takes ~45 seconds. I'm using `cassanda-spark-connector` library, and run the local web server which also hosts the Spark. So my setup is roughly like this:

In sbt:

```
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j")),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.1" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j")),
    "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.4.0-M3" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"))
```

In code I have a singleton that hosts `SparkContext` and `CassandraSQLContetx`. It's then called from the servlet. Here's how the singleton code looks like:

```
object SparkModel {

  val conf =
    new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("core")
      .setMaster("local")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlC = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
  sqlC.setKeyspace("core")

  val df: DataFrame = sqlC.cassandraSql(
    "SELECT email, target_entity_id, target_entity_type " +
    "FROM tracking_events " +
    "LEFT JOIN customers " +
    "WHERE entity_type = 'User' AND entity_id = customer_id")
}
```

And here how I use it:

```
get("/spark") {
  SparkModel.df.collect().map(r => TrackingEvent(r.getString(0), r.getString(1), r.getString(2))).toList
}
```

Cassandra, Spark and the web app run on the same host in virtual machine on my Macbook Pro with decent specs. Cassandra queries by themselves take  10-20 milliseconds.

When I call this endpoint for the first time, it takes 70-80 seconds to return the result. Subsequent queries take ~45 seconds. The log of the subsequent operation looks like this:

```
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Starting job: collect at V1Servlet.scala:1146
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Got job 1 (collect at V1Servlet.scala:1146) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Final stage: ResultStage 1(collect at V1Servlet.scala:1146)
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Parents of final stage: List()
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Missing parents: List()
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[29] at collect at V1Servlet.scala:1146), which has no missing parents
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(18696) called with curMem=26661, maxMem=825564856
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 18.3 KB, free 787.3 MB)
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - ensureFreeSpace(8345) called with curMem=45357, maxMem=825564856
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 8.1 KB, free 787.3 MB)
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:56289 (size: 8.1 KB, free: 787.3 MB)
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:874
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[29] at collect at V1Servlet.scala:1146)
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.s.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
12:48:50 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, NODE_LOCAL, 59413 bytes)
12:48:50 INFO  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
12:48:50 INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - New Cassandra host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 added
12:48:50 INFO  c.d.s.c.cql.CassandraConnector - Connected to Cassandra cluster: Super Cluster
12:49:11 INFO  o.a.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on localhost:56289 in memory (size: 8.0 KB, free: 787.3 MB)
12:49:35 INFO  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 6124 bytes result sent to driver
12:49:35 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 45199 ms on localhost (1/1)
12:49:35 INFO  o.a.s.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
12:49:35 INFO  o.a.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler - ResultStage 1 (collect at V1Servlet.scala:1146) finished in 45.199 s
```

As you can see from the log, the longest pauses are between these 3 lines (21 + 24 seconds):

```
12:48:50 INFO  c.d.s.c.cql.CassandraConnector - Connected to Cassandra cluster: Super Cluster
12:49:11 INFO  o.a.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo - Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on localhost:56289 in memory (size: 8.0 KB, free: 787.3 MB)
12:49:35 INFO  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 6124 bytes result sent to driver
```

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong. What's that? How can I improve this?

**EDIT:** Important addition: the size of the tables is tiny (~200 entries for `tracking_events`, ~20 for `customers`), so reading them in their whole into memory shouldn't take any significant time. And it's a local Cassandra installation, no cluster, no networking is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  "SELECT email, target_entity_id, target_entity_type " +
    "FROM tracking_events " +
    "LEFT JOIN customers " +
    "WHERE entity_type = 'User' AND entity_id = customer_id")
```

This query will read all of the data from both the tracking_events and customers table. I would compare the performance to just doing a SELECT COUNT(*) on both tables. If it is significantly different then there may be an issue but my guess is this is just the amount of time it takes to read both tables entirely into memory.

There are a few knobs for tuning how reads are done and since the defaults are oriented towards a much a bigger dataset you may want to change these.

```
spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb  approx amount of data to be fetched into a Spark partition  64 MB
spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows    number of CQL rows fetched per driver request   1000
```

I would make sure you are generating as many tasks as you have cores (at the minimum) so you can take advantage of all of your resources. To do this shrink the input.split.size

The fetch size controls how many rows are paged at a time by an executor core so increasing this can increase speed in some use cases.

Comment: Excellent answer Russ!  I've noticed the same performance hit, but assumed that it was because my Spark cluster was running on my local VM.

Comment: I can't start my Cassandra instance right now for some reason, but what's important is, those 2 tables are tiny. `tracking_events` has 200 entries, and `customers` only about 20. It can't really take so long because of data loading.

Comment: Why don't you check the UI, it should break down the timing exactly for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I don't run the standalone Spark, only as a dependency to my web app. I tried to go to localhost:4040, as documented, but there's nothing there.

Comment: Okay, managed to run the Cassandra. With a query like `SELECT Count(*) FROM tracking_events` the roundtrip takes ~2 seconds, much faster.

Comment: Not the query you need to run the code through spark, Compare the performance to:
   val rdd1 =sc.cassandraTable("ks","tracking_events")
   val rdd2 = sc.cassandraTable("ks","customers")
   rdd1.count
   rdd2.count
   // There should also be a shuffle here but we can ignore that for now

Comment: The UI is only up while the application is running unless you persist the event log with spark.eventLog.enabled = true + spark.eventLog.dir = some dir. See the spark docs for more info

Comment: Job of `sc.cassandraTable("core", "tracking_events").count` + `sc.cassandraTable("core", "customers").count` takes 2.5 seconds to complete.

Comment: Then it seems like the Spark repartitioning is going to be the slow part. Not much we can do to fix that other than minimize your default parallelism (since the job is so small.) If you could see the ui this might give you an idea of how many tasks are created during the repartitioning event. You probably only want 1 for such a small job. So a default shuffle parallelism of 1. `spark.default.parallelism` is the conf parameter for that.

Comment: Setting the `spark.default.parallelism` to 1 didn't change anything. And I've managed to run the UI and added the screenshot with the job summary. http://imgur.com/Y05r7FX

Comment: Since there is only one task, I'm afraid thats the end of the road as far as I can see. For some reason that Cartesian product must be very slow ... I can't imagine anything else to really mess with here. On the plus side I'm imagining most of this is overhead and probably won't change if you scale up the data significantly.

Comment: That's okay, but, I guess, I've been totally misled by the applicability of Spark to real-time querying. This actually is very sad. I need something that can respond in under 1 second at longest.

Comment: Spark isn't really made for real time querying, it's more of a batch analytics framework, maybe you meant to look for something like Solr?/ElasticSerach?

Comment: for set size in spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb , visit [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31586690/5035204)