# spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been using [pyspark-cassandra 0.1.5](https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra) with spark 1.4.1(latest release).

But normal counting of 1519784 records of cassandra is taking 70 secs.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583249/apache-spark-taking-5-to-6-minutes-for-simple-count-of-1-billon-rows-from-cassan?lq=1) question in stackoverflow, I came to know about the use of "**spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb**" while defining SparkConf, will help in reducing the time.

But i get the following error, while including the same in my python code

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.cassandraTable.
: com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ConfigCheck$ConnectorConfigurationException: Invalid Config Variables
Only known spark.cassandra.* variables are allowed when using the Spark Cassandra Connector.
spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb is not a valid Spark Cassandra Connector variable.
Possible matches:
spark.cassandra.input.split.size
```

I believe I am doing something silly. I am very new to Spark, please help.

Answer (score 0):

pyspark-cassandra is using the Spark Cassandra connector 1.2.x and in that version the parameter is named `spark.cassandra.input.split.size`. See the error message there which is telling you that `...split_size_in_mb` is not valid, but maybe you meant `...split.size`.